# Do the effects of a Potion of Speed or Potion of Heroism disappear if the character becomes unconscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, potions, unconscious, duration

If a player is under the effect of a [*potion of speed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-speed):

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the *haste* spell for 1 minute (no concentration required). The potion’s yellow fluid is streaked with black and swirls on its own.

or a [*potion of heroism*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-heroism):

> For 1 hour after drinking it, you gain 10 temporary hit points that last for 1 hour. For the same Duration, you are under the effect of the *bless* spell (no concentration required). This blue potion bubbles and steams as if boiling.

Do those effects wear off if the player is reduced to 0 hit points and becomes unconscious before the 1-hour duration is over?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### They don't wear off

As you indicate, the duration of either potion is one hour, and there is no limitation should the affected creature become unconscious.

The [general rules for magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items) also make no mention of such a limitation. In fact, this is the only excerpt I could find addressing durations and potions:

> Many items, such as potions, bypass the casting of a spell and confer the spell's effects, with their usual duration. Certain items make exceptions to these rules, changing the casting time, duration, or other parts of a spell.

In the case of a *potion of speed* and *potion of heroism*, the exception to the Spellcasting rules comes in the removal of the Concentration requirement (the usual reason a spell would end should the caster become Unconscious).

**Since there is nothing that would stop the effect if the creature is unconscious, the effect will last the entire hour regardless.**

Answer (score 4):

## No

The [unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Unconscious) condition would end the spell effects if they required [concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration).  The potion's specifically state that is not the case.